# Extract Reusable Code into Abstract Base Class with Generic Parameters

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core

I am trying to achieve a design in c# like below.

```
void Main()
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddScoped(typeof(RedisRepository<>));
    serviceCollection.AddScoped(typeof(CommitterBase<IDto>), typeof(ACommitter));
    serviceCollection.AddScoped(typeof(CommitterBase<IDto>), typeof(BCommitter));
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<Client>();
    var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var client = services.GetRequiredService<Client>();
    client.Dump();
}

public class RedisRepository<T> where T: IDto
{
    public void Add(T dto)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Added data");
    }
}

public interface IDto
{   
}

public class ADto: IDto
{   
}

public class BDto : IDto
{
}
```

and :

```
public abstract class CommitterBase<T> where T: IDto
{
    public CommitterBase(RedisRepository<T> repo)
    {   }

    public void Commit()
    {
        var dto = GenerateDto();
        //do something with dto here
    }

    protected abstract T GenerateDto();
}
```

and its implementations:

```
public class ACommitter : CommitterBase<ADto>
{
    public ACommitter(RedisRepository<ADto> repo): base(repo)
    {   }
    
    protected override ADto GenerateDto()
    {
        return new ADto();
    }
}

public class BCommitter : CommitterBase<BDto>
{
    public BCommitter(RedisRepository<BDto> repo) : base(repo)
    {

    }
    protected override BDto GenerateDto()
    {
        return new BDto();
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public Client(IEnumerable<CommitterBase<IDto>> committers)
    {   }
}
```

error that I get

```
Implementation type 'BCommitter' can't be converted to 
    service type 'UserQuery+CommitterBase`1[IDto]'
```

I understand from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71375538/abstract-base-class-with-generic-types-and-resolving-the-implementations-using-d) that this error is expected. Just wondering how to achieve similar effect without encountering the error. My aim is to extract reusable code into an Abstract Base Class and let the implementations do bare minimum.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, it is often better to put reusable code in a helper class or extension method than in a base class. See also [Core reuse via inheritance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187876/code-reuse-via-inheritance). But your question does not provide much background, so it is difficult to tell what the most appropriate solution would be. The specific problem should be trivial to solve by slapping a non-generic interface on `CommitterBase`, but I cannot tell if that would be practical or not.

Answer (score 0):

Interface cannot be instantiated and `IDto` is interface. So you can register specific implementation to your interface.

I little bit refactored code to use generic parameters.
This is yor base abstract class:

```
public abstract class CommitterBase<T> where T : IDto
{
    public CommitterBase(RedisRepository<T> repo)
    { }

    public void Commit()
    {
        var dto = GenerateDto();
        //do something with dto here
    }

    protected abstract T GenerateDto();
}
```

And its concrete implementations such as `ACommitter`:

```
public class ACommitter<T> : CommitterBase<T> where T : IDto, new()
{
    public ACommitter(RedisRepository<T> repo) : base(repo)
    { }

    protected override T GenerateDto()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

and `BCommitter`:

```
public class BCommitter<T> : CommitterBase<T> where T: IDto, new()
{
    public T FooBar { get; set; }

    public BCommitter(RedisRepository<T> repo) : base(repo)
    {

    }


    protected override T GenerateDto()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

and `RedisRepository`:

```
public class RedisRepository<T> where T : IDto
{
    public void Add(T dto)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Added data");
    }
}
```

and `Client` class:

```
public class Client<T> where T : IDto, new()
{
    public CommitterBase<T> CommitterBaseProperty { get; set; }
    
    public Client(CommitterBase<T> committer) // if you want all instances of committers, 
                                              // then you need to create a factory
                                              // and inject it through DI
    {
        CommitterBaseProperty = committer;
    }
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<RedisRepository<ADto>>();
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<RedisRepository<BDto>>();
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<CommitterBase<ADto>, ACommitter<ADto>>();
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<CommitterBase<BDto>, BCommitter<BDto>>();
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<Client<ADto>>();

    ServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    CommitterBase<ADto> committerBase = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<CommitterBase<ADto>>();
    CommitterBase<BDto> committerBase_B = 
        serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<CommitterBase<BDto>>();
    committerBase.Commit();
    Client<ADto> client = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Client<ADto>>();       
}
```